# How to combine images into a stack

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to combine 3 images into a stack as on the picture below:

[image]

Stack must have size 48x48.

Is there any way to do it? I believe that it is possible to do it only by means of the CSS and using a little bit JS.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Position: absolute isn't an option?

Comment: If it is a dynamic stack of images (ie the number of images can change) then you may need a little js too (to calculate size and apply z-index's) but as they are going to be so small, do you really need to stack them like that?  You'll barely be able to see the effect

Comment: "when it's in a stack - it must adjust size." - it is not possible to check whether they are stacked without javascript. Then you would have to adjust height and width based on javascript conditions.

Comment: JavaScript needs to be used to get the height and width of the images and then adjust them in stack. I guess With pure CSS it can't be done.

Comment: @BasSlagter, absolute position can be an option.

Comment: There are tricks in CSS that would allow you to do this: http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/  But you would have to choose a maximum number you'll support (which makes sense anyway).

Comment: Ok, maybe it needs a little bit JS.

Comment: @Pete, I simplify the question. I need only 3 images in a stack.

Comment: I actually voted to close as it is too broad, I completely understand what you want but you need to make an effort and then let us know at what point you got stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible: https://jsfiddle.net/ncrLqwbu/

It basically makes sure that there are a specific amount of elements, which specifies the element size:

```
.block:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.block:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
}
```

And then it decides how much alignment it needs to do:

```
.block:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div:nth-child(2) {top: 6px; left: 6px}
```

But that scales n^2 which means the amount of CSS will increase exponentially

This solution is very inconvenient as CSS can't count the elements in their parent, which means that you need to add more and more CSS classes for each tier of element count. It would be much easier to do with Javascript

**Edit:**

Added a SASS version: https://jsfiddle.net/k7nupbrd/1/

**Edit #2:**

The question has since been edited. At first it required support for N amount of elements.

Comment: Thank you, I sure that solution with N amount of elements will be userfull for me.